# Proof that $\exists_{ m \in [a;b]} g'(m) = \frac{1}{e} $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g: [0;3] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable, and 
$$g(0) = 1 \\ g(1)=2 \\ g(3) = 2 $$
Proof that $$\exists_{ m \in [0;3]} g'(m) = \frac{1}{e} $$

### My try

I think that I should use there one of Rolle, Cauchy, Lagrange theorem. I have and idea with the second one.  
From cauchy theorem:
$$\exists_{ m \in [0;3]} (f(1)-f(0))\cdot g'(m) = (g(1)-g(0))\cdot f'(m)$$
$$ g'(m) = \frac{(g(1)-g(0))\cdot f'(m)}{f(b)-f(a)} = \frac{1}{f(1)-f(0)}\cdot f'(m) = \frac{1}{e} $$
and know I should find function which will pass my requirements.
I tried $f(x)= e^x$, $f(x) = ex$ and others similar but none of them doesn't pass what I need. 
 I don't even know that this approach is correct (or if it is just not stupid) but I wonder that there is a function which can help me to proof that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) implies that
$$
1 = \frac{g(1)-g(0)}{1-0} = g'(a) \text{ for some } a \in (0,1) \\
0 = \frac{g(3)-g(1)}{3-1} = g'(b) \text{ for some } b \in (1,3)
$$
Then [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) implies that $g'$ takes every value between $0$ and $1$ in the interval $[a, b]$, in particular the value $1/e$. You can prove that directly by considering the function
$$
f(x) = g(x) - \frac xe
$$
which must have a maximum in the interval $[a, b]$, where the derivative vanishes.

Comment: I had Rolle's theorem but in this theorem (on my lecture) was condition that $f(a)=f(b)$ and there $f(0) \neq f(1)$ I don't understand why $g'(a) = 1 \text{ for some } a \in (0,1)$. Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @trolley: My fault, what you need first is the mean value theorem (which is a consequence of Rolle's theorem).

Comment: Ahh, yes, now everything is pretty clear, thanks a lot for explanation!

Comment: One more question @Martin, why are we convinced that g' is continous (to use darboux)?

Comment: @trolley: Darboux's theorem does *not* require $g'$ to be continuous! That is what makes the theorem interesting.

Comment: we use darboux to $g'$, not to $g$, so $g'$ should be continuous - have I right?

Comment: @trolley: Darboux's theorem is applied to $g$. It states that if $g$ is differentiable then $g'$ has the intermediate value property. – Note also that I added a sketch of a  proof for this particular case. The continuity of $g'$ is *not* needed.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know darboux theorem in that form. I also didn't checked your link because I was convinced that you think about chmm... "classic version" (weird). Anyway, thanks for explanation (one more time :D) !